# Optaplanner Constraint Streams Join Problem Fact and Planning Entity

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to join the planning entity and a problem fact in a constraint streams but my IDE throws an error on that: `Cannot resolve method 'join(java.lang.Class<Edge>, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner<A,B>)'`

My problem structure is very similar to the transportation problem. I have nodes and edges and want to calculate the quantity of the edges.

My main problem fact is:

```
class Node{
   UUID id;
   int itemsInInventory;
   ...
}
```

And the planning entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
class Edge{
   Node from;
   Node to; 
   @PlanningVariable
   int itemsTransported;

   getFromId(){return from.getId()}
   getToId(){return to.getId()}

}
```

The code of the constraint is:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
            .join(Edge.class, equal(Edge::getFromId, Edge::getId))
            ...
}
```

If I try to join the edges with the edges for example:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
            .join(Node, equal(Node:: getId, Node::getId)) //EDITED
            ...
}
```

This works without an error. Is the reason, that I try to join Nodes into the Edges on the Edge property in the Nodes? Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I do not understand how your latter example works:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
        .join(Node, equal(Node:: getId, Edge::getId))
        ...
}
```

In this case, you are joining `Node` and another `Node`. The `equal(...)` joiner therefore needs to use `Node` on both sides, like so:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
        .join(Node.class, equal(Node::getId, Node::getId))
        ...
}
```

Or, more shortly:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
        .join(Node.class, equal(Node::getId))
        ...
}
```

This is also the reason why your first example does not compile:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
        .join(Edge.class, equal(Edge::getFromId, Edge::getId))
        ...
}
```

In this case, you are joining `Node` with `Edge`, so the `equal(...)` joiner needs to use `Node` on the left and `Edge` on the right, like so:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Node.class)
        .join(Edge.class, equal(Node::getId, Edge::getFromId))
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly the case, I did not know, that the order (left/right) in the equal function of the join is relevant. Now it works. The second example was just an example and I had a mistake (should by Node::getId on both sides and no Edge:getId)

Comment: Do you maybe know a source for explanations of the constraints streams? The official Optaplanner documentation is not very helpful for that. After the join, I want to summarize all "itemsTransported" in the edges for the node. I tried a groupBy but I cannot figure out which parameters I need to group the BiConstraintStream after the join.

Comment: I suggest you ask another question for that.